# why the console is giving the error Bad request(400) when i am trying to fetch the backend function 'createOrder'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch, mern

I am using the braintree for the payment gateway , the payment feature is working fine when I tested with their given credit cards for test but after the payment it should create an order when the backend fetch code is hit but it is not working.
I am using this code to fetch the backend function,

```
import { API } from "../../backend";

export const createOrder = (userId,token,orderData) => {
    return fetch(`${API}/order/create/${userId}`, {  //getting error at this line
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({order: orderData})
    }).then(response => {
        return response.json();
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
};
```

backend code is,

```
    router.param("userId", getUserById);
    router.post(
  "/order/create/:userId",
  isSignedIn,
  isAuthenticated,
  pushOrderInPurchaseList,
  updateStock,
  CreateOrder       
);
```

I am getting the error 'Bad Request'. The same fetching request is working on other places like for create product and category , API is working fine there but not here.

Answer (score 0):

Some reason for 400 BAD REQUEST

URL String Syntax Error. The HTTP error 400 can occur due to incorrectly typed URL, malformed syntax, or a URL that contains illegal characters